# How to fix Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE )

Tags: windows-8

I have a wordpress blog of mine. For the couple of days I'm unable to upload anything to my blog or perform some actions like installing plugins.
Everytime I try to do so, I am receiving "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data." in Google Chrome and an error page in IE.
But when I try to do the same thing from a friend's PC or a VM running in my PC or a PC connected to my home network  the operation is perfect. I'm there there is no hosting or web server issue. There might be some problemm with the network setting in my PC. I'm on Windows 8 Pro 64 bit.

Please suggest me any solution for this strange and unusual problem.